# Message Extension failing to load on Android devices

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a fully designed and running a message extension on the MS-Teams Desktop app and iPhone app.
But when I am running on the same app on Android, it fails to load, after certain tries, it crashes the MS-Teams application.

Comment: Can we get on call to discuss this? Please write to us on microsoftdevteams@microsoft.com

Comment: @Manish-MSFT I tried to contact you at the above address, received Message Blocked. Can you provide another way for contacting?

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct address microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com. Thanks. Let me know here once you drop a mail.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT, Just sent you the mail. Thanks

Comment: @GauravGupta can you describe the error log you are getting when the app is crashing, that will be really helpful to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. We are able to repro this at our end and we are tracking it here: https://domoreexp.visualstudio.com/MSTeams/_workitems/edit/1472217

Please follow [this issue](https://domoreexp.visualstudio.com/MSTeams/_workitems/edit/1472217) for updates/progress/questions.

Comment: The Microsoft Teams Version: 1416/1.0.0.2021020402 solved the issue on android for me.